# Formula for finding difference between multiples in excel

Tags: excel, formula

Formula is to find the difference of multiples to be used in excel for an ordering form. For example, orders of items must be placed in multiples of 6, for every 6 ordered you get one free. So for 6 calculated result needs to display "1 item free". For 12 calculated result needs to show "2 items free". For 11 would need to display "Order 1 more, or 5 less".

How do I define this formula/calculation in an excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [modular math](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mod.php):

e.g.  14 items purchased, buy in groups of 5:

```
14 mod 5 = 4

buy 1 more (5 - 4) or 4 less.
```